# How can I show texts only if they fit in the arc in Chart.Js 2.8.0?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a doughnut chart in [Chart.Js](https://www.chartjs.org/) with the [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/) enabled. How can I write the string into the segments only if they fit into the segment of the chart?

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 0.3, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: function(value) {
          return value + " kWh";
        }
      }
    },
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.6.0"></script>
</body>
```

The following image shows my problem:
[image]

Comment: @Adnan Sharif: Thank you for the edit, I did not know how to add this example snippet runner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can work? Only adding a label when the value is above a certain threshold?

```js
let data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 0.3, 3];
let sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  sum += data[i]
}

let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: data, 
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: function(value) {
          percentage = (value / sum) * 100;
          if (percentage < 1) {
             return "";
          }
          return value + " kWh";
        }
      }
    },
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.6.0"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This works depending on the size of the chart itself. If the chart is really small, the threshold would need to be adjusted dynamically to the size of the arc. But I will use this solution for the moment.

Comment: Additionally, this will not work if all values are small. E.g. if there are 3 values and all are below 1, every value will get about 33% of the arc ;) Check this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/6035nL1u/. Generally, I like the idea with the threshold but there needs to be a method to get the arc (e.g. in degrees) of the current segement the text is written to.

Comment: Yes. let me see if there is a way to make this smarter.

Comment: There does that work better? I just used a straight percentage for now. But you should be able to calculate the arc angle too

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: In my case, I had to sum up the data like that: `let sum = dataSets.reduce((t, d) => t + d.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b), 0).toFixed(2);` where `dataSets` is the whole dataset object (Was the only thing I had to iterate).